# programatically take average of columns but not value = "3" in excel

Tags: excel, vba

In excel using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) how do I programatically take the average of a column, excluding empty fields and the values equal to "3".

I have a column with a header "isCompleted" where the value can be 0 (no) or 1 (yes) or 3 (not relevant)

to see how many have been completed I'd take the average of only the 0 and 1 scores. How do I do that programatically?

Comment: Do you want to do this in VBScript or in VBA? Despite having similarities the two languages are not the same.

Comment: I'm assuming VBA is more likely, edited as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*xl03*

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
MsgBox .SumIf(Range("A:A"), "<3") / .CountIf(Range("A:A"), "<3")
End With
```

*or, assuming you have xl07 or higher*

I think you want

```
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(Range("A:A"), Range("A:A"), "<3")

'or perhaps
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(Range("A:A"), Range("A:A"), "<=1")
```

to average the 0 and 1 values

Comment: Updated to cater for 2003.

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA, this formula will do the job:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,A:A,"<>3")/COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>3",A:A,">=0")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need it to be in VBA, because it is part of a script where I extract data from another file and do calculations on it (this being one of them). Is there a programmatic way to apply this to expression to a column?

Comment: yes. you can access the functions with `Application.WorksheetFunction.` :-)

Comment: This is summing 3s on the top line and dividing by the number of 3s in the numerator - it will either be 3 or undefined (no 3's)

Comment: @brettdj: If forgot to quote the > as always. thanks for pointing this out, I corrected it. is there any easy way in SO to post VBA code with > or < without need to quote?